# How to filter features from coordinates

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I'm using mapbox-gl and mapbox gl draw.

On the map, there will be a layer which has all markers. And I implemented polygon draw on that map using mapbox-gl-draw.
After that, I use `turf.js` to get the points within the drawn pologon. So, now, I have those points.

But those points are just points, not fully features. I want to query that features using those points.

Let's say I get these coordonites points as a result of `turf`.

```
[
[2, 2],
[3, 3],
[4, 4]
]
```

On the above mentioned layer, I've added markers and one of those looks like below:

```
{
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {
      title: name,
      id: id,
    },
    geometry: { coordinates: [long, lat], type: "Point" },
}
```

So, how can I get those features using above points?

Answer (score 1):

This data-wrangling task comes up a lot in spatial web development.  All you need to do is build out a geojson Point feature for each set of coordinates.  You can use `Array.map()` for this:

```
const pointFeaturesArray = coordinatesArray.map((coordinates) => {
  return {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: coordinates
    },
    properties: {}
  }
})
```

`pointFeaturesArray` is now an array of valid geojson point features, but what you probably want is a `FeatureCollection` (an array of geojson features is not valid geojson on its own).  To do that, just set this arrray to the `features` property in a `FeatureCollection`:

```
const pointsFC = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: pointFeaturesArray
}
```

You may want to test this geojson to make sure it is valid.  One way to do this is to log it to the console, then copy and paste it into [geojson.io](https://geojson.io).  If it is valid it will appear on the map, if it is not valid, you will see some red highlighting in the code editor area telling you where something is wrong.

`pointsFC` is now ready to use in `map.addSource()`:

```
map.addSource('mypointfeatures', {
  type: 'geojson',
  source: pointsFC
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. What I need is - using that coordinates array, I want to query those `features` from the layer that I have set. 
Let's say on the map there are 100 markers. I include 3 markers inside my drawn polygon. so, as the result of `turf`, I get the above coordinates array. Now, how can I get those 3 `features` (markers) from the map using those result, so that I can get the `properties` from the `features` object?